# Regression with GARCH error term

Tags: regression, time-series, maximum-likelihood, heteroscedasticity, garch

Let's consider the following multivariate regression ($y_{t}$ and $x_{t}$ below are matrixes of appropriate size) where the error term is assumed to follow a GARCH process:
$$y_{t}=\beta x_{t} + e_{t}$$
with $e_{t}=\sigma_{t} Z_{t}$, where $\sigma_{t}$ is a matrix of appropriate size resulting from the Cholesky decomposition of the conditional covariance matrix $\sigma_{t}^{2}$, $\sigma_{t}^{2}$ follows a GARCH process and $Z_{t}$ is a vector of appropriate size of iid random innovations (let's assume normally distributed with mean 0 and unit variance for each element). Therefore, this regression is estimated via MLE (not OLS). Assuming that $x_{t}$ has a certain conditional covariance matrix denoted by $V_{t}$ and assuming that there is no conditional correlation between $e_{t}$ and the regressors $x_{t}$, shall the following hold for each $t$ (like in a common unconditional regression)?
$$\text{Var}_{t}(y_{t})=\sigma^{2}_{t}=\text{Var}_{t}(\beta x_{t}+e_{t})= \beta \text{Var}_{t}(x_{t})\beta^{t}+\text{Var}_{t}(e_{t})=\beta V_{t}\beta^{t}+\text{Var}_{t}(e_{t})$$

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/155856-linear-regression-with-garch-egarch-errors does this answer your question?

Comment: @Aksakal thanks but I saw that.. that refers to the estimation in matlab and it's ok, but my question was more theoretical, in the sense that: should the conditional variance of the dependent variable be equal to the sum of the conditional variance of the regressors and error term (assuming regressors and independent from the errors)?

Comment: conditioning on what? If you condition on $x_t$ then there's no variance $V_t$, it's a determinitistic value

Comment: @Aksakal conditioning on t-1

Comment: @Aksakal $V_{t}$ is the conditional covariance matrix of the regressors where conditional mean conditional on the info set available at time t-1

Comment: If it's $I_{t-1}$ then I don't see why the sum of variances wouldn't hold. Though I'd look at literature on psudo $R^2$ for time series models.

Comment: @Aksakal thanks a lot.. I didn’t know there existed a pseudo R2 for time series regressions with Garch Error term, I found not much materials on this although I searched quite a bit.. I will make another attempt (if you have something ready without the need for searching please link it).. otherwise I will try in my own once again..

Comment: You seem to be using $\sigma_t^2$ to denote variance of $y_t$ as well as $\varepsilon_t$, that might need a correction. Using a capital letter to denote a matrix could be more instructive. Also, it could be helpful to specify conditioning explicitly in the formulas. What is *common unconditional regression*? And $y_t$, $x_t$ are actually vectors, right? (Haha, you can probably tell I am still in the mode of reviewing a paper, which I did recently, picking on all the large and small imprecisions.)