# Is ARIMAx a transfer function model?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima

I would like to know if the ARIMAx model is considered a  transfer function model. If the answer is no, further explanation on what are differences would be appreciated.

Comment: u betcha https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/420726/is-arimax-a-transfer-function-model and https://autobox.com/pdfs/A.pdf

Comment: u betcha https://autobox.com/pdfs/A.pdf ...........................

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Hyndman has a brief explanation of the subject [here](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/). ARIMAX is a transfer model $$y_t=\frac {\beta(B)} {v(B)} x_t+\frac{\theta(B)}{\phi(B)}z_t$$
where $x_t$ is contemporaneous exogenous variables and $\beta(B)=\beta$ is a simple coefficient matrix. The transfer function approach would have $\beta(B)$ with a set of possibly lagged exogenous variables.

A thing to be aware of is that sometimes by ARIMAX people, including Hyndman himself, call a different special case of transfer function model that is referred to as regARIMA in MATLAB or regression with ARIMA errors. A case in point is [SARIMAX](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX.html) in Python statsmodels. The regression with arima errors model is:
$$y_t=\beta x_t+\frac{\theta(B)}{\phi(B)}z_t$$

Comment: today i posted a question on a similar topic (i.e. regression with GARCH error term), I provide the link [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/420701/regression-with-garch-error-term) do you know the answer? Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you for your great answer @Aksakal.

Comment: I have a blog post detailing all the naming confusion about ARIMAX, transfer function models (in its narrower sense and broader sense), and why different people are using different terms. If you want more details: https://ruqinren.wordpress.com/2020/02/21/all-the-confusion-about-arima-arimax-transfer-function-dynamic-regression-models/